# is it possible to create a api which a particular website can access only and no other website can access it?

Tags: django, server

**Let me explain in detail**

I've 2 servers hosted and one of them for Back-end and other is for Front-end.

Back-end server : 127.0.0.1:8000 (just for explaining)
Front-end server : 127.1.1.1:9000

User requests UI from Front-end server and if he wants to create an account on my website he needs to send POST request to 127.0.0.1:8000/create-account/ and this works fine.

If I open console of other web site or make use of Postman, I'm able to achieve the same results.
So I want to prevent this thing and only allow anyone to create account from my we bsite only.

**Methods which I've tried**

1. I've used `windows.location()` and sent it to server and then verify if domain name matches, but in this method everyone can just pass it simply via `fetch()`.
2. I've used allow only IP address, ut if I push my web site in production Other visitors get 403 error.

I develop back-end with help of Django and rustlang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible. You can make it hard for entry-level programmers to reverse-engineer your solution, but there isn't any way to prevent access to your API if you are going to allow access to it from some public UI.

IP address-based restriction will not work here because your backend will receive the IP of the user. In this case, you will be blocking access to users, not to any UI. Even the host header verification doesn't work here as anyone can use a proxy server, i.e. NGINX, to override the headers and can fake the request to originate from an intended website.

IP address-based authorization can work only if API calls originate from a server and your API server receives the same IP address for each API call. But for your use case, it isn't applicable.

The older techniques like CSRF are useless too as anyone can easily retrieve the token and can send it. In short, if you make something public, it can be reverse-engineered. If you are accepting public registrations, there shouldn't be anything to worry about the registration source. You should think about solutions like email verification etc. to reduce the spam if that's the concern.

Comment: So how companies like Facebook and Google deals with this type of situation as we cannot register a new user to their server using their API. so should I route the registration page to the same origine

Comment: There are tons of software that automate Google and FB account creation. As I said anything can be reverse-engineered if it's visible to the public. And you can register a user if you do things correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your frontend solve a recaptcha and send the solution to the backend. Verify the solution before accepting the request. It is still possible to bypass although a bit harder.

Comment: is it not possible to make my API only access via 127.1.1.1:9000 only and if someone tries to access it from 123.4.5.6:100 it will give him an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at JWT tokens for Zero Trust.  Expire them after one time use.  It will force the client to re-authenticate each time to get a new JWT token.

Only allow "pass through" authentication if on a client joined on your domain who can authenticate with "Kerberos".

Then you will have protection against hackers.